# How does tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose behave with stride and padding?

Tags: tensorflow

While a convolution layer in TensorFlow has a complete description https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution, transposed convolution does not have one.

Although tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose has a reference to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf, it is not complete.

Is there any documentation that describes how tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose behaves?

Comment: Here's the answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12110/97316

Answer (score -1):

Conv2DTranspose is often used as upsampling for an image/feature map. The code below use 1X1 filter kernel to show how the input is padded with zero. the code is for tensorflow 2.0, add enable_eager_execution() with tensorflow1.x

```
data = tf.ones([2,2],tf.float32,"input_data")
input_layer = tf.reshape(data, [-1, 2, 2, 1])
transpose2d = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='ones', strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', use_bias=False)
x = transpose2d(input_layer)
print(x)
```

The input is

- 1,1
- 1,1

The x is

- 1,0,1,0
- 0,0,0,0
- 1,0,1,0
- 0,0,0,0

you can change the stride value to see the diffrence

Comment: Thanks but I wanna know not contcrete examples but general explanation with strides and paddings which might be described with some mathematic formulas.